# How to reuse decomposed LU matrix to solve Ax = b in JBLAS

Tags: java, linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

I have started working with JBLAS, but I am facing an issue,

```
doubleMatrix x = Solve.solve(A,b);
```

This gives the results just fine. But if i wish to do a recalculation to find **Ax = b1**, then it will go all over again to decompose to get **A = LU** or maybe **A = QR** . but that is redundant as the **A** matrix remains same.

I want it to decompose A using this:

```
Decompose.LUDecomposition<DoubleMatrix> out = Decompose.lu(A);
```

and then pass the object generated to a solve function to get the desired output. Using this way it won't require doing decompositions all over again if only the **b** value changes.

**Is it possible?? Please help. Or am i to write that function from scratch..**